# Runtime error in LLVM Pass, the message is "Ptr must be a pointer to Val type!"' failed."

Tags: c++, llvm, llvm-ir, llvm-c++-api

I want to insert "malloc" to target code using llvm pass.

To do this, my codes are as below.

```
allocated = new GlobalVariable(module,
    Type::getInt64PtrTy(*ctx),
    false,
    GlobalValue::CommonLinkage,
    0,
    "main_func_address"
);
Function* mainFunction = module.getFunction("main");

BasicBlock& mbb = mainFunction->getEntryBlock();

IRBuilder<> IRB(dyn_cast<Instruction>(mbb.getFirstInsertionPt()));
std::vector<Value*> malloc_arg;
Value* size_malloc = ConstantInt::get(Type::getInt32Ty(*ctx), 1);
errs()<<"Create Call\n";
IRB.CreateCall(mallocFunc, size_malloc);
errs()<<"Create Store\n";
IRB.CreateStore(size_malloc, allocated);
```

Error occurs at "IRB.CreateStore". 
Error message is "void llvm::StoreInst::AssertOK(): Assertion `getOperand(0)->getType() == cast(getOperand(1)->getType())->getElementType() && "Ptr must be a pointer to Val type!"' failed."
How can I do?

Comment: You're trying to write a 32-bit number to a 64-bit variable.